# VB Array Syntax

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am declaring an array as certain cell values in a worksheet. I will show the code below. In this case, is the first cell (upper leftmost cell) in this array at position (0,0) or (1,1)? In other words, I need to know if this is 0 based or not for correct coding purposes. Thanks!

'runningavg' is declared as a variant before this statement:

```
runningavg = Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Range("A4:BX2004").Value
```

Comment: in your case, always `(1,1)`... because ranges (with at least 2 cells) allways start at 1...

Comment: @DirkReichel thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()

    Dim arr

    arr = Sheet1.Range("a1:a8")

    Debug.Print LBound(arr) ' FirstRow
    Debug.Print UBound(arr) ' LastRow

    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 2) ' FirstColumn
    Debug.Print UBound(arr, 2) ' LastColumn

End Sub
```